# Ask user for a number / integer value

Tags: android, preference

For a timeout preference I need to ask the user for a number. Is there some kidn of "number control" on android or do I have to use a text input and check if the text given by the user if a number? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graphical layout view for the textbox you can select
Properties>Input Type>Number
or in the xml view you can add "android:inputType="number"" to the EditText

Answer (score 1):

try this to your edit text field.. this will accept only number..

```
android:inputType="number"
```

add this property to your edit text..

Comment: thank you, also correct answer, but jpevarnek was slightly faster, so I accepted his answer ;-)